# How to transform GBM trees to rpart or ctree in R?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart, party, gbm

Do you know any way to transform trees obtained with gbm package (extracted with function `pretty.gbm.tree`) to any of the objects concerning decision tree building (`rpart` or `ctree`)?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, it should be possible to transform the `gbm` trees to `party` or `constparty` objects from package `partykit`. That is the improved reimplementation of the `party` package which allows to represent both `ctree` and `rpart` objects in the same framework. We haven't added an interface to `gbm` because you are typically not interested in the hundreds or thousands of trees in a boosted model. As Greg writes on the manual page of the `pretty.gbm.tree` function: *This function is mostly for debugging purposes and to satisfy some users' curiosity.* If you want to have a look at how the `party` trees can be constructed from scratch, see `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")`.

Comment: One important use for the individual trees is to extract the important interactions or non-linearities to use in another type of model, or to determine a more compact set of trees to deploy.  See package [inTrees](http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/web/packages/inTrees/index.html)